# OpenGL rendering glitch

Tags: opengl, nvidia

I'm working on a 3D game project with a bunch of people. The project runs fine on all of their machines but mine. On my computer the skybox texture intermittently disappears and the rendering goes awfully bad.

We've all been working on Windows XP with Visual Studio 2008, and the only significant difference between my machine and my co-workers is that my computer has a Nvidia 9400 GT graphics card, which, I guess, is the thing to blame.

Here's a screenshot, skybox-less. Is there any setting in OpenGL or the Nvidia video manager that I can tweak to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Post a minimal, complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Does the skybox disappear, or does it turn white ?

Comment: @rotoglup: the skybox disappears and reappears. the effect is white lines crossing the screen.

Comment: ok, could you post a screenshot of the 'white lines crossing' effect ? Also, in your question, "Here's a screenshot, skybox-less.", do you mean it is a screenshot after the skybox has disappeared ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this can depend on the texture size. Could tyou try with a texture in which dimensions are power of two ?